# Is there a way to change the animation type of multiple objects at once?

Tags: slideshow, google-slides

I have a slide with multiple object I want to animate.
I select them and click the "animate" button that adds the default animation effect type to all of the selected objects.

Let's say that the default is "appear" but I want all of the selected objects to use "fade in" instead.

I can do this one by one for each object, but that is quite tedious. Is there a way to apply this to all of the objects at once?

Comment: This is currently not possible, unfortunately. There's no option of changing animation types in bulk, either via the Slides interface, Apps Script, or Slides API. I suggest submitting a feature request in Google's [Issue Tracker] (https://issuetracker.google.com/) for now if you're interested with using this feature in the future.